# What is the probability that the product of $20$ random numbers between $1$ and $2$ is greater than $10000$?

Tags: probability, products

Twenty random real numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{20}$ are chosen such that $1\le a_i \le 2$. What is the probability that their product is greater than $10000$?

(By random, I mean each real number in the interval $[1,2]$ has an equal chance of being chosen. All twenty numbers are chosen independently of each other.)

Comment: I think you should ask for a general solution for the product of $N$ i.i.d. $a_i \sim U[1,2]$ such that the product of $a_i$ is less than some $1<K < 2^N$

Comment: That's equivalent to finding the probably that the sum of $N$ uncorrelated numbers $a_i \sim \log U[1,2]$ (in the range [0, log 2]) is less than $\log K$, which can be found by doing lots of convolutions.

Comment: "Each real number...has an equal chance of being chosen": You can't do that! What would this chance be? It can't be non-zero, and it seems like it can't be zero either (although technically it is). You have to say something like, "for any interval $[r,s] \subset [1,2$], the chance that $a_i \in [r,s]$ is $s-r$." This is called the _uniform distribution_ on $[1,2]$.

Comment: @kennytm That's similar to what I thought, but I'm finding that the integrals need to be computed in a very piecewise manner, so not tractable for n=20.

Comment: @John Smith, Does an approximation suffice via CLT, or do you mean an exact answer?

Comment: @John Smith ..and I agree with TonyK and jameselmore that you should edit the question to read that $a_i$ independent and identically distributed Uniform r.v. on $[1,2]$ and omit the explanation in parenthesis.

Comment: You can make better than an approximation via the central limit theorem, you can make a saddlepoint approximation!

Comment: $n=20$ is often cited as a rule of thumb for using the CLT. So if this was a homework problem I would interpret it as an exercise in converting a problem about products into a problem about sums and applying CLT.

Answer (score 2):

This is more thinking aloud than real answer.

A paper called [Product of n independent uniform random variables](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Emaxog/publications2/ProductRVs.pdf) by Carl P. Dettmann, Orestis Georgiou seems to be relevant. Its central result is following theorem:

[image]

In our case $a=1$, $b=2$, $n=20$.

After a lot of cumbersome but doable calculations it is possible to obtain the probability from the question using PDF from above Theorem 1.

Answer (score 2):

Here´s an aproximation with a normal distribution.

$${Let\quad  Y_i=\ln( X_i)    \quad   where    \quad X_i \thicksim U(1,2) \quad i=1,2, \ldots,20 }  \qquad {then \quad f_{Y_i}(y_i)=e^{y_i}\quad 0\leq{y_i}\leq \ln(2)}                  $$

$$And \space then\quad {\mu =\int_0^{\ln(2)} ye^y dy =0.386294}\qquad{E[y^2]=\int_0^{\ln(2)} y^2 e^y dy =0.188317 }\qquad{\sigma=0.197722}$$
$$Now,\space from\space probability\space we\space know \space that:\qquad {\lim_{n\to \infty}  Pr(Z_n= \dfrac{S_n-n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt n}\leq z )=\Phi (z)} $$
$$ You´re\space looking\space for \qquad {\prod_{i=1}^{n}  X_i \geq C  }\qquad$$$${This\space means\qquad S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}  \ln(X_i)=\ln(\prod_{i=1}^{n} X_i) \geq \ln(C) }\qquad $$$${Applying\space the \space C.L.T\space theorem:}$$$$\qquad \qquad {P(S_n \geq \ln(C))=P(S_n -n \mu \geq \ln(C) - n \mu)=P(\dfrac{S_n-n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt n}\geq \dfrac{\ln(C)-n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt n})={1-P(\dfrac{S_n-n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt n}\leq \dfrac{\ln(C)-n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt n})}\approx 1-\Phi( \dfrac{\ln(C)-n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt n})}$$
In your case n=20 (akward, since it´s not big enough to normal-approximate) and C= 10,000.

So the probability (approximately ) is  4.6596% (Montecarlo simulations says 4.51%).

Answer (score 1):

Using the CLT on the logs as suggest by @kennytm might give a
satisfactory approximation. (Of course the CLT does not apply
directly to products.)

As long as we're discussing approximations, a simulation gave approximately 0.045 as the answer. 
Repeated it several times to check computational stability.
One run is shown below.
(Each row of the matrix has 20 observations from UNIF(1, 2);
the penultimate statement takes products of rows; the
last statement estimates the desired probability baed on a
million performances of the experiment.)

```
 m = 10^6; n = 20
 MAT = matrix(runif(m*n, 1, 2), nrow=m)
 y = apply(MAT, 1, prod)
 mean(y > 10000)
 ## 0.045291
```

*Addendum:* A histogram of the sums of logs of 20 obs
is nicely fit by a normal density curve. This seems to
lend credibility to the approach of using the CLT on logs.

Comment: I think that an answer that uses a simulation should explain why you think the simulation is accurate, and if possible a confidence interval.

Comment: With a standard error of about $2$ in the ten-thousandths digit?